# Node.js - Out of memory when making calls to search index

Tags: node.js, stream, elasticsearch

I am trying to read from a csv file and insert the data into an elasticsearch index.  As below, I use a readstream and listen in on the "data" event.  My problem is, I quickly run out of memory using this approach.  I'm guessing it's because the elasticsearch module (elastical) is making a REST every time, and the number of such requests build up.

I am pretty new, so is there a way for me to fix this so it doesn't run out of memory?  Any general patterns or techniques?

```
stream.on('data', function (doc) {
    // create a json from doc
    client.index('entities', 'command', json, function (err, res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pause the stream when you get data and resume it when the request completes.

```
stream.on('data', function (doc) {
    stream.pause();
    // create a json from doc
    client.index('entities', 'command', json, function (err, res) {
        stream.resume();
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

Weird thing about your code is you're not using `doc` anywhere in that function. I'm guessing you're not posting your entire code.

Comment: Indeed, I just posted a skeleton, and I omitted the part where I create a var json from doc.  However, even after doing this I am still running into the memory problem.  Can I directly call stream.resume from within the callback function?

Comment: Yes if the `stream` is visible in the callback.